# Bloomberg data retrieval in R : Invalid override field id specified error

Tags: r, bloomberg

I would like to retrieve power hedging data using Rbbg bloomberg package in R and I know this formula works in excel :

```
=BDH("VATT SS Equity","BI_%_ELECTRIC_POWER_HEDGED","01/01/2000","","GEOGRAPHIC_LOCATION_OVERRIDE=EUCN","BI_CONTRACT_MATURITY_OVERRIDE=CY12","FUND_PER=Q")
```

But when I try this in R :

```
conn<-blpConnect(log.level="off")
data<-bdh(conn,"VATT SS Equity","BI_PER_ELECTRIC_POWER_HEDGED","20000101","","GEOGRAPHIC_LOCATION_OVERRIDE=EUCN","BI_CONTRACT_MATURITY_OVERRIDE=CY12","FUND_PER=Q")
```

I get the following error message :

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  org.findata.blpwrapper.WrapperException: response error: Invalid override field id specified [nid:217]
```

What should I change in the formula to make it work ?

Thanks

Edit: Indeed it is BI_PCT_ELECTRIC_POWER_HEDGED, however the problem does not come from here but from the overrides.

Comment: `BI_PER_ELECTRIC_POWER_HEDGED` should probably be `BI_PCT_ELECTRIC_POWER_HEDGED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns an empty variable for me, but it doesn't throw an error so it might get you on the right track.

The way you specify options is different in the current version it seems.

```
data<-bdh(conn,"VATT SS Equity", "BI_PER_ELECTRIC_POWER_HEDGED","20000101","",
 override_fields=c("GEOGRAPHIC_LOCATION_OVERRIDE",
"BI_CONTRACT_MATURITY_OVERRIDE",
   override_values=c("EUCN","CY12"),
   option_names="periodicitySelection",
   option_values="QUARTERLY")
```

The doc where I found the correct syntax is here: [RBloomberg](http://findata.org/rbloomberg/rbloomberg-manual-0-4-144.pdf).  It was written in 2010 for the predecessor package (before Bloomberg complained about using their name) but I guess it works!  I think the convention of enumerating the list of option names then the option values is odd compared to your assumption that OPTION=VALUE was correct, but there you go.